# Can I programmatically create an empty subdirectory under the shared media directory DCIM or the Download directory in Android?

Tags: android, mediastore, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

My app needs targetSDK to be the latest 33, can't apply MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and also to work on Android 10 or newer phones with scoped storage enabled.

Neither the MediaStore API nor the SAF API seems to work, with the former not knowing how to implement it and the latter requiring manual creation by the user.

Can anyone give me an example? thank you very much!

Comment: Why not MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: Indeed. Using MediaStore you cannot create empty directories as the MediaStore.insert() is for creating files.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved  Google Play restricts the use of this permission. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955

Answer (score -2):

You can just use mkdir() and mkdirs() to do what you want in the classic way.

Also with SAF you can do it.

Comment: blackapps contribution never consists of a solution. Often he feels it necessary to criticise posters